# How to authenticated same credentials with wordpress and node

Tags: node.js, wordpress, angular

I have two websites, one is wordpress and other is angular/node. How to login wordpress site useing same credentials as angular site. We don't want the user to create another account in wordpress. We should manage this for angular site. How to implemented this scenario.

Comment: Please see [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON Web Tokens. The [JWT Authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin will allow you to log in from your JS app.

You make a POST request to `/WP-JSON/JWT-AUTH/V1/TOKEN` with the username and password to get the token (if the credentials are correct), and each time you make a request to the WordPress site you add `Authorization : Bearer [token]` to your request header.